# Django static css not loaded?

Tags: python, html, css, django

So my app has the following structure: base.html, which contains the nav and the links to the stylesheets and the home.html file, which loads the nav via extends. However, i can't really modify the css inside my home.html file, any suggestions whats wrong?

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>App</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.png' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">


...## navbar etc.



 <div id="body">
        <div class="container">
          {% block page %}
          {% endblock %}

        </div>
      </div>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% load staticfiles %}

{% block page %}



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="{% static 'img/banner.gif'%}" class="banner">
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in the base.html file, i load the app.css file via static method.

However, changing for example the banner class in the home.html isn't working at all:

```
#body .banner {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

No errors in the terminal / console. The app.css file works for the base.html by the way.

Comment: May be you for  python manage.py collectstatic OR you may be not working on web server and in settings.py debug = False

Comment: have you tried {% load static %} instead of staticfiles? and if not can you post the settings of static and your main urls file

Comment: Try reloading your cache. Sometimes it's that simple

Comment: try it by opening the browser in incognito mode

Comment: Thanks all. I think it had something with the cache to do. I started the server on a different port and used incognito mode and its works now fine, even without incognito. Appreciate it! If you want, post your answer and i vote i up! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ctrl + F5, in django you have to reload your cache after making changes to static files.